# Nativescript issue : Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s)

Tags: ios, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, xcode9

I currently have an issue with an iOS app that I'm developing with native script and angular. I recently updated Xcode to 9 version and did a Clean job within Xcode for my project and then the issue happened, now when I try to execute tns run iOS here is the output :

```
    tns run ios
Searching for devices...
Executing before-liveSync hook from /Users/onols/Desktop/ClubiesApp/hooks/before-liveSync/nativescript-angular-sync.js
Executing before-prepare hook from /Users/onols/Desktop/ClubiesApp/hooks/before-prepare/nativescript-dev-typescript.js
Found peer TypeScript 2.4.2
app/tns_modules/@angular/animations/browser/src/render/animation_engine_next.d.ts(26,26): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).

app/tns_modules/@angular/animations/browser/src/render/transition_animation_engine.d.ts(104,26): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
...
node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts(703,48): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts(705,62): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts(707,58): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts(760,60): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts(762,29): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts(766,47): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts(768,65): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts(770,60): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts(772,27): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts(774,56): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts(776,42): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts(778,57): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts(780,31): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts(782,63): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts(784,63): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts(786,65): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts(794,35): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts(797,91): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts(799,94): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts(801,40): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts(804,97): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts(807,67): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts(810,57): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts(812,61): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts(814,65): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts(816,57): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts(818,46): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts(820,50): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts(823,61): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/nativescript-toast/index.d.ts(8,25): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier ''long''.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(58,70): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(2,60): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(3,89): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/tns-core-modules/file-system/file-system.d.ts(35,15): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/tns-core-modules/file-system/file-system.d.ts(46,30): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/tns-core-modules/file-system/file-system.d.ts(85,34): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/tns-core-modules/file-system/file-system.d.ts(105,52): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/tns-core-modules/file-system/file-system.d.ts(154,14): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/tns-core-modules/file-system/file-system.d.ts(177,20): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/tns-core-modules/file-system/file-system.d.ts(183,53): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/tns-core-modules/tns-core-modules.d.ts(14,18): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/tns-core-modules/tns-core-modules.d.ts(19,58): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/animation/animation.d.ts(122,32): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/animation/keyframe-animation.d.ts(101,34): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/dialogs/dialogs.d.ts(30,60): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/dialogs/dialogs.d.ts(36,47): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).

node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/dialogs/dialogs.d.ts(42,43): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/dialogs/dialogs.d.ts(48,51): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/dialogs/dialogs.d.ts(55,64): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/dialogs/dialogs.d.ts(61,49): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/dialogs/dialogs.d.ts(69,79): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/dialogs/dialogs.d.ts(75,47): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/dialogs/dialogs.d.ts(83,92): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/dialogs/dialogs.d.ts(89,49): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(1354,14): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(1374,124): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(1375,15): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(1381,16): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(1540,32): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(1541,38): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(1542,64): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(1544,63): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(1546,52): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(1555,32): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(1556,29): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(1558,63): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(1559,30): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(5788,13): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(5789,48): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(7337,56): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(7397,51): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(7406,22): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(7410,14): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(7411,59): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(7412,30): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(7413,15): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(7414,28): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(7436,24): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(7576,59): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(7709,52): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(7770,99): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(7771,103): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(8251,109): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(8411,67): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(8482,23): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(8483,35): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(8598,14): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(8599,13): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(8610,19): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(8626,41): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(8952,24): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(8953,61): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(8954,55): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(8967,20): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(9031,15): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(9041,15): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(9042,13): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(9267,132): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(9270,118): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(9271,144): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(9275,136): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(9278,144): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(9279,145): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(9385,17): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(9386,19): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(9533,21): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(9534,45): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(9536,68): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(9572,69): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(9573,19): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(9574,15): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(11597,28): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(11973,72): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(11974,160): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(13312,169): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(13313,217): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(13513,20): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(13514,13): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(13515,13): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(13516,13): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(13517,17): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(13658,52): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(14655,182): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(14656,230): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(14687,65): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts(211,11): error TS2428: All declarations of 'Promise' must have identical type parameters.

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts(220,60): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts(228,52): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts(25,25): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts(33,113): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts(41,284): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts(49,255): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts(57,229): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts(65,203): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts(73,177): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts(81,151): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts(89,125): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts(97,98): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts(105,72): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts(113,45): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts(121,284): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts(129,255): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts(137,229): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts(145,203): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts(153,177): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts(161,151): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts(169,125): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts(177,99): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts(185,73): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts(193,46): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts(200,26): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts(207,29): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts(214,44): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts(220,16): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.symbol.wellknown.d.ts(168,11): error TS2428: All declarations of 'Promise' must have identical type parameters.

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts(1288,11): error TS2428: All declarations of 'Promise' must have identical type parameters.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts(1295,211): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts(1302,112): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).

Unable to apply changes on device: 30b9a1b5dc6b154e1ec801e7dcf5f15d1f8636fb. Error is: TypeScript compiler failed with exit code 1.
Building project...
Xcode build...
=== BUILD TARGET ClubiesApp OF PROJECT ClubiesApp WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
build-debug.xcconfig line 3: Unable to find included file "../plugins-debug.xcconfig"
=== BUILD TARGET ClubiesApp OF PROJECT ClubiesApp WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
error: could not read data from '/Users/onols/Desktop/ClubiesApp/platforms/ios/ClubiesApp/ClubiesApp-Info.plist': The file “ClubiesApp-Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
** BUILD FAILED **

Unable to apply changes on device: 3887748A-6E73-4736-8D32-A439446C0352. Error is: Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 65.
Executing after-watch hook from /Users/onols/Desktop/ClubiesApp/hooks/after-watch/nativescript-dev-typescript.js
```

I cannot find a solution for this, can someone know where this could come from ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a similar problem. What was really making me insane is that my app was working for Android, then I tried to compile it for iOS, then it started to present the TS2314 errror, and then when I tried to run the Android app again it also started to present the same error.

I started a new project and began installing the dependencies and copying the files one by one to the new one.

The new project started to show the same problem when I copied the tns_modules folder inside the app folder.

Then I deleted tns_modules from both the new and old projects, ran the app again and it worked on both. :-/

So my suggestion is:

1. Backup your project.
2. Delete Android and iOS from the ./platforms folder.
3. Delete the tns_modules from the ./app folder.
4. Run the app again.

If this doesn't work, you could try to do the same I did. Start an empty project, check that it correctly compiles both for Android and iOS, then transfer each file and module and check when the project stops working.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and sorry for the delay of my personal answer ! This specific issue effectively comes from tns_module as I followed your instruction and it solved the issue !
Thank you again !